# Where is the pelican function section is in pelican documentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, static-site, pelican

## Where is Function information present in documenation?

`articles_page.previous_page_number()`

This function I don't know where is written. From where it get imported and used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Jinja2 to group articles by date and paginate in Pelican?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814797/how-can-i-use-jinja2-to-group-articles-by-date-and-paginate-in-pelican)

Answer (score 0):

It is defined in [paginator.py](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/7a26f509dfc76d7fcd4d2d28eac02aae0a8fbd17/pelican/paginator.py#L89) line 89 as of today.